# Find datetime in timestamp column of pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestamp, say 1611903555682, which I convert into a datetime, i.e. 2021-01-29 07:59:15, and I want to find out whether this datetime is stored in a timestamp column of a pandas dataframe, which looks like:

['2021-05-10T19:53:38.205000000' '2021-05-10T19:53:39.210000000'
'2021-05-10T19:53:40.215000000' ... '2021-02-08T11:36:08.639000000'
'2021-02-08T11:36:09.644000000' '2021-02-08T11:36:10.649000000']

I want the comparison to look only at YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS, so ignoring the milliseconds.

I tried with the following

```
 if pd.Timestamp(datetime.fromtimestamp(last_timestamp/1000).strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S") ) in df_processed_timestamps['time'].values:
        print('Value is already in dataframe.')
        return
```

But this condition is never entered, even if values are actually in the dataframe (I checked it by printing the dataframe). Am I doing a conversion error? In fact, if I run:

```
print(str(pd.Timestamp(datetime.fromtimestamp(last_timestamp/1000).strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S") )))
     
print(df_processed_timestamps['time'].values)
```

I get:

```
 2021-01-29 07:59:15
['2021-05-10T19:53:38.205000000' '2021-05-10T19:53:39.210000000'
 '2021-05-10T19:53:40.215000000' ... '2021-02-08T11:36:08.639000000'
 '2021-02-08T11:36:09.644000000' '2021-02-08T11:36:10.649000000']
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: pandas datetime uses nanosecond precision by default. Are you sure you want to compare things with that precision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you convert `timestamp` to `%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S` but values in `time` column is not that format.

You can convert the `time` column to seconds then check if `timestamp` is in column

```py
timestamp = 1611903555682
isin = timestamp in pd.to_datetime(df['time']).values.astype(np.int64) // (10**6)
```

```
print(pd.to_datetime(df['time']).values.astype(np.int64) // (10**6))

[1620676418205 1620676419210 1620676420215 1612784168639 1612784169644
 1612784170649]

print(isin)

False
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The dataframe column is unfortunately quite big (about one million rows) and the processing is a bit slow. Would you have a suggestion about converting the single value timestamp instead of the whole dataframe column?

Comment: @gisk How about `datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp/1000).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f000") in df['time']`?

Comment: this would compare also millisecond, right? I would like the precision to be on "seconds"

Comment: @gisk It's already divided by 1000, I don't think it's a problem.